# Why need to judge the element if or not exsit in a collection in removeAll(Collection c)？

Tags: java, collections, removeall

could you help me understand this snippet? I don't understand why this function have to check the collection contains the element before remove it. Since the iterator is from the collection, all element returned by iterator is definitely in collection.So I think it's a waste of time. Thank you a lot

```
   public boolean removeAll(Collection<?> c) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(c);
    boolean modified = false;
    Iterator<?> it = iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (c.contains(it.next())) {//I don't understand
            it.remove();
            modified = true;
        }
    }
    return modified;
}
```

Comment: what is `iterator()` method doing? Share that code as well

Comment: It seems iterator() is another local method which might be operating on another collection? based on code you posted, it is not pointing to c.

Comment: The `iterator` is from _this_ collection.  `c.contains` is checking if that element is in a _different_ collection.

Comment: this snippet is form  java.util.AbstractCollection class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like an implementation of `Set`'s [removeAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll-java.util.Collection-).

The `iterator` is not iterating on the `Collection` passed to the method. It is iterating on the `Set` on which the method was called.

```
set1.removeAll(collection2);
```

You are iterating over the elements of `set1` and check for each one of them whether it belongs to `collection2` before removing it from the `Set`.

Answer (score 0):

That snippet is from a class that implements `Collection`. The method only removes items from the local class instance (through the local `iterator()`) when the `Collection` `c` also contains an item that is `equals`.